# Resolve clash of JS jqueryui / fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my HTML page, I have included a Jquery's fancybox and it worked well. But when I add a jqueryui script *too*, I get a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
```

(from login.js, which uses one fancybox call, which indeed works w/o the offending new line.) My script inclusions are as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"> </script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>                   
<link type="text/css" href="./jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./jqueryui/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- the above commented out line is the offending one; once removed, page works well  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't mentioned it, so it must be asked: can you include fancybox after jq-ui and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that, and it seems it indeed solves the problem. Any idea why? (And is there a way to upvote/mark your comment as solution?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice, i see no need for it, anyway try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jqueryui/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"> </script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>                   
<link type="text/css" href="./jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

this uses jQuery 1.7.1, then you load jQuery UI then you load fancybox

Comment: As Kato's comment above, including the fancybox POST JQueryUI solves the problem. (Nicola, note I believe JQueryUI must be included before its JS itself) Does JQueryUI *include* JQuery itself? Anyway, solved for now -- thanks!